# Java programming using semaphores and shared variables

Tags: java, semaphore, parallel-processing

Hey everyone, I have a task to perform at school and really don't know how to get started.
I don't want the whole solution, but rather tips and how to get started with this. Sorry but I'm new to programming. Here's the task:

A bulletin board (40p) is used to post apartment rental notices. Each rental notice includes 3 tear-away tabs with the phone number on it. A group of n students scans the board looking for apartments. Each student randomly selects 3 different apartments, and tries to remove one tab from each of 3 corresponding notices. If a student succeeds in taking 3 tabs that s/he has selected, s/he leaves, otherwise s/he does not take any, pauses a random amount time, and then tries again with a new selection of 3 different apartments. The simulation ends when all students have left. Assume the board has space for roundup(n/3) notices. Develop a parallel program that simulates actions of the students using only semaphores for synchronization. Represent the students as concurrent processes. Be sure to declare and initialize shared variables that you use for process interaction and synchronization. Try to maximize concurrency. Shortly explain how your solution works and how it avoids deadlock.

---

<sup>**update to include info provided as an *answer***</sup>

Here's my code so far! Am I in the right direction!?

```
private static Semaphore[] apartments;

public void setApartments()
{
    apartments = new Semaphore[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        apartments[i] = new Semaphore(3);
}

@Override
    public void run()
    {
        setApartments();
        Random random = new Random();

    while(counter < 3)
    {
        try
        {
            acquired = apartments[random.nextInt(3)].tryAcquire();
            if(acquired)
                System.out.println("Student" + id + " succeded.");
            else
                System.out.println("Student" + id + " failed.");

            counter++;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

I have one problem that i can't figure out.
I have 4 threads running at the same time, talking one permit at a time from: 
static Semaphore tabsA = new Semaphore(3);

So i thread will run forever cause, it doesn't get any. But if I use tabsA.release(); when the thread didn't meet the requirements, all four threads can take the permits even when there are 3 permits in Semaphore(3). I could even run 10 threds, and it would work. How come?

Comment: You need to use this: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html, presumably

Comment: So given the course lecture(s) and book/reference information, **explain some thoughts/ideas/algorithms on how a solution may be approached**. There does not need to be anything Java-specific in this outline -- simply use the parallel/concurrency concepts taught in class (and "use only semaphores").

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, I don't like answering homework questions directly, but you might want to focus your research on the [`Random`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class with its [`nextInt(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method, the [`List<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface and its implementations, the [`Runnable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) interface (and [`Thread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class), and the [`Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) class with its [`tryAcquire()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#tryAcquire%28%29) and [`release()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release%28%29) methods).

Comment: Just make sure you don't call a semaphore's `release()` method unless you actually managed to acquire a permit from it first... (I've NEVER made a mistake like that before or anything! *whistles innocently*)

Comment: use try { get permit } finally { release permit } here :)

Comment: @ChrisDennett: Er, according to the spec for this app, you only want to release permits if you couldn't gather all three randomly selected ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing this **serially** (i.e. one student at a time) just to get your basic objects/methods/algorithms working properly.  This should be relatively simple for you.  Then come back when you start refactoring for parallelism and ask pertinent questions.

Comment: So one permit corresponds to one notice?

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to represent each rental notice as having a [Semaphore](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for the number of available tabs.

Semaphores are basically a way of declaring that a limited number of resources exist. When a process attempts to acquire a Semaphore it is basically asking for a permit to use the resource that the Semaphore is symbolically guarding. When a process which has acquired a permit is done with the resource, it should release the permit so that another process can acquire it. If a process wants to wait (potentially forever) for a permit to be available in Java it calls `Semaphore.acquire()`. If a process just wants to try to get a permit if it is immediately available or do something else otherwise, in Java it call `Semaphore.tryAcquire()`.